# Как в .iso образе по адресу перейти с одного файла на другой?

Tags: ассемблер, ос, boot, bios, fasm

Есть 2 файла, fboot и fkernel, они находятся на разных адресах, как скомпилировать их в .bin так, чтобы в .iso образе, можно было по адресу перейти с одного файла на другой ?

Сам код написан на FASM, c прерываниями BIOS и взят с сайта metanit.com
https://metanit.com/assembler/articles/MiniOS.php

fboot

```
org 7c00h  

start:
        cli             
            xor ax,ax
            mov ds,ax
            mov es,ax
            mov ss,ax
            mov sp,07C00h
        sti

        mov ax, 0002h
        int 10h

        mov dx,0h
        call SetCursorPos

        mov bp, msg
        mov cx, 13
        call PrintMes

        add dh,1
        call SetCursorPos
        mov bp, Con
        mov cx, 23
        call PrintMes

;----------------------------------

Continue:
        mov ah,10h
        int 16h

        cmp al, 0Dh
        jz Kernel
jmp Continue

;----------------------------------

Kernel:
        mov ax,0000h
        mov es,ax
        mov bx,500h
        mov ch,0
        mov cl,02h
        mov dh,0
        mov dl,80h
        mov al,01h
        mov ah,02h
        int 13h
jmp 0000:0500h

;----------------------------------

PrintMes:
        mov bl,04h
        mov ax,1301h
        int 10h
        ret

SetCursorPos:
        mov ah,2h
        xor bh,bh
        int 10h
        ret

;----------------------------------

msg db 'OS Loading...',0
Con db 'Press Enter to Continue',0

times(512-2-($-07C00h)) db 0
db 055h,0AAh
```

fkernel

```
org 500h
message:
    mov ax, 0002h
        int 10h

    mov dx,0h
    call SetCursorPos
        mov bp, msg
        mov cx, 20
        mov bl,04h
        xor bh,bh
        mov ax,1301h
        int 10h

        add dh,2
        call SetCursorPos
        mov si,0

Command:
    mov ah,10h
        int 16h
        cmp ah, 0Eh
        jz Delete_symbol
        cmp al, 0Dh
        jz Input_Command
        mov [string+si],al
        inc si
        mov ah,09h
        mov bx,0004h
        mov cx,1
        int 10h
        add dl,1
    call SetCursorPos
    jmp Command

Input_Command:
    mov ax,cs
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov di,string
    push si
    mov si,write
    mov cx,5
    ;rep cmpsb
    ;je wrt
    pop si
    jmp Command

Delete_symbol:
    cmp dl,0
    jz Command
    sub dl,1
    call SetCursorPos
    mov al,20h
    mov [string + si],al
    mov ah,09h
    mov bx,0004h
        mov cx,1
        int 10h
        dec si
    jmp Command

SetCursorPos:
        mov ah,2h
        xor bh,bh
        int 10h
        ret

msg db 'Input the command...',0
write db 'write',0
string db 5 dup(?) ;буфер для ввода командыs
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду компоновку двух скомпилированных файлов (загрузчик и ядро) в один образ, то скомпилируйте следующий листинг (он находится на указанной вами странице):

```
macro align value { db value-1 - ($ + value-1) mod (value) dup 0 }
HEADS = 1
SPT = 3 ;3 сектора по 512 байт
Begin:
    file "fboot.bin",512 ; загрузчик
    file "fkernel.bin" ; ядро
    align HEADS*SPT*512
```